# Changing CSS of <img> when hovering over `<button>. The <img> is inside <button>

Tags: html, css

I would like an easier / efficient way to edit the CSS of the `<img class "search-button>` when hovering over `<button class="search-button">` instead of changing the `search-button` itself like I have done below.

The fact that the `img` is changing height and the button isn't is also bizarre to me. I would think changing the `height` attribute would change the `height` of the button and not the `height` of the `img`

Is it possible to do without using Javascipt and a pure CSS method? An explanation would be appreciated as I am self-studying and more information is far valuable than just a solution.

**After fix and edit - My Question : Could it be simplier?**

HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="search-button">
    <img class="search-button-img" src="http://teacherweb.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/search.png" alt="">
</button>
```

CSS

```
search-button {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  width:145px;
  height:145px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.search-button-img {
  height:80%;
}

.search-button:hover .search-button-img { /*Fixed hover space */
  margin-top:-1px;
  margin-left:-1px;
  height:100%;
}
```

Original : http://jsfiddle.net/x8xwxg3z/

Updated (Working Well) : http://jsfiddle.net/x8xwxg3z/5/

*random magnifier image for example

Comment: If you write .search-button:hover (without space) the button will change the height

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x8xwxg3z/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Tramsform scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```css
.search-button {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  width:145px;
  height:145px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.search-button-img {
  width: 80%;
  transition: transform .3s ease
}

.search-button-img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2)
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="search-button"><img class="search-button-img" src="http://teacherweb.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/search.png" alt=""></button>
```

Or apply the `:hover` on the parent

```css
.search-button {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  width:145px;
  height:145px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.search-button-img {
  width: 80%;
  transition: transform .3s ease
}

.search-button:hover .search-button-img{
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2)
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="search-button">
  <img class="search-button-img" src="http://teacherweb.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/search.png" alt="">
</button>
```

Comment: You might want to check your spelling in your link ;)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution, although it's nice. It uses the css `transform` which is only supported in IE10 and above (IE9 knows it with the `-ms` prefix, below it won't work). So be aware, that this won't work for a few people. For nice animation take a look at the `transition` property in CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: @wawa please stop learning from w3schools you are doing it wrong use `developer.mozilla.org` , `html5rocks.com` , `webplatform.org` , `developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/` or `dev.w3.org`  here is the reason why http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Tambo true (was just the first resource Google showed). But anyway, take a look at http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/ 2D Transforms: IE 10+ and that's my point. Your code, although it's nice and good CSS3, isn't compatible with all browsers used. I know it sucks, but there are still a few guys and girls out there with IE9. Therefore I'd prefer a solution, that will work at least in IE9 at the moment. (Let's hope that we won't have to care about IE9 and below in half a year or so...).

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood you right, you want only the image to become bigger, but not the button?

You could try the following:

```
.search-button:hover .search-button-img {
    height: 90%;
}
```

instead of:

```
.search-button :hover {
  margin-top:-1px;
  margin-left:-1px;
  height:100%;
}
```

This won't work, because you're using a space between the class/selector and the pseudo class. In CSS you write `selector:pseudoclass` as soon as you use a space, CSS interprets that as a child. So `.foo .bar` would adress the div with the class `bar` in `<div class="foo"><div class="bar">Baz</div></div>`. CSS Selectors can be ID's, Classes or simply selectors. Classes are adressed by a `.` in front and IDs by a `#`. I hope this helps.

With CSS you are able to adress a child element like the image. And it's Javascript, what you meant not Java ;)

Answer (score 1):

your problem is from the space between :hover and your class so remove the space

```
.search-button:hover {
  margin-top:-1px;
  margin-left:-1px;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/x8xwxg3z/3/

and css code is here:

```
.search-button {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  width:105px;
  height:105px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
    position:relative; transition:all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
}

.search-button-img {
  height:50px;
    position:absolute; top:10px; left:20px
}

.search-button:hover {
  margin-top:-1px;
  margin-left:-1px;
  height:500px;
      width:80%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want is to make bigger the button without making bigger the image. The image is getting bigger because it has a % size (it depends of his parent, in this case, the button).

Anyway:

`.search-button:hover{}` refers to: when you hover over the button do this to the button.

`.search-button:hover .search-button-img{}` refers to: when you hover over the button do this to the image.

Then you only need the change, that you want to do.